# Java spring. Annotations for tricky serialization to json and xml

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, serialization

I'm trying to rewrite some API serialization from custom mappers to annotation-based style and faced with one hard mapping (which was earlier custom-serialized to json and xml separately) that I can not "translate" to. (Serialization is made with Jackson.)

In the POJO we have a collection, e.g.

```
class Data {
    Set<Integer>  tags; 
}
```

which should be serialized in xml like:

```
<tags>
    <tag id="1"/>
    <tag id="2"/>
</tags>
```

and in json like:

```
{
    "tags":[1,2]
}
```

Strait method with

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="tags")
@XmlElement(name="tag")
```

gives good json, but incorrect xml like

```
<root>
    <tags>
        <tag>1<tag/>
        <tag>2<tag/>
    </tags>
</root>
```

cause there is no attribute specification.

I tried to wrap a bit with:

```
class Data{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="tags")
    @XmlElement(name="tag")
    Set<Tag> tags;
}

class Tag{
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    Integer id;
}
```

But this produces unwanted key in json format, like:

```
"tags":[
    {"tag":{"id":1}},
    {"tag":{"id":2}}
]
```

Ok, then. I tried to specify custom json serializer(implementing JsonSerializer and injecting with @JsonSerialize(using = ...) ), but seems it also affects xml "render".

Is it possible to do the trick with annotations only? Or mb is it possible somehow use default json serialization and custom xml serializtaion for some class? .e.g.
use custom xml serialization only for Reasons class in such way

```
class Data {
    @XmlElement("tags")
    Reasons tags;
}
```

but let all surrounding data be "render" with general strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a getter annotated with @JsonValue will tell Jackson to produce a single value, without any field name.

This mapping:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data{

    public Set<Tag> tags;
}

public class Tag{

    @XmlAttribute
    public Integer id;

    @JsonValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Will then produce:

```
{"tags":[2,1]}
```

And:

```
<data><tags id="2"/><tags id="1"/></data>
```

PS: You're using JAXB annotations, i don't think Jackson will honor them. 
To get the XML result above, you need to use JAXB:

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class, Tag.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.marshal(value, writer);
    System.out.println(writer.getBuffer().toString());
```

As a final note, i'm not super fan of using a single mapping for multiple representations. It's probably good for simple stuff, but if your code grows more complex than this, i strongly suggest you create two sets of classes (one for XML mapping and one for JSON), maybe with a common interface.

Comment: But jackson supports JAXB annotations, doesn't it? I mean xml serialization is correct with all those Xml.... But if I'll add JsonValue then xml looses its attributes. 

Mb it is possible to specify xml serialization per class?

Comment: Okay, I've googled around, and the answer is yes, if you add this dependency : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations . Do you have it in your project? My "vanilla" jackson serializer completely ignored them.

Comment: (Anyway my solution is only tested with a jackson ObjectMapper for JSON, and a JAXB Mashaller for the XML)

Comment: Tnx for investigations. It is definitely defined in ivy as adependency, but mb it is somehow misconfigured. I am working above all premade configurations, so mb there is a trick. Ill ask local spring configuration guru for that moment tomorrow and report the results.

Comment: Shame on me. Answer is correct according to question stated, but in my specific case another workaround with custom serializers did the trick.